# Help deciphering IMAP traffic

Tags: email, imap

I have configured Windows Live Mail for my Gmail account. It uses IMAP for incoming and SMTP for outgoing mail. I collected packets recvd/sent by the application over a period of 4 hours using Netmon. I observed that the server every now or then sends a TLS packet of TCP payload length 39. I decrypted the packet and it contains:

```
* 554 EXISTS
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: The server is basically saying it has 554 messages. Each message is assigned a unique identifier. I have told Live Mail to check for new mail every 5 minutes and I indeed see see this packet every 5 minutes.